# May AWS reap memory associated with the initialization code of a warm AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have heard of a phenomenon called *partial cold starts* described in resources like below:

https://pages.awscloud.com/rs/112-TZM-766/images/2020_0316-SRV_Slide-Deck.pdf

It means that AWS deallocate the resources associated with the initialization code of an AWS Lambda function, which turns a warm container into a partially cold container.

I think I observe such behavior when using provisioned concurrency, where a "warm" container has a significant increase in latency after being idle for +5 minutes.

I can't find any information in official AWS documentation. Can someone provide me with relevant links and a formal description?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71345002/whats-happening-when-an-aws-lambda-function-freezes